# Restart script on outofmemory error

Tags: java, tomcat

Our production tomcat server is crashing. Logs show outofmemory error. Java heap space.

I wrote a script to restart the server and provided jvm option

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=E:\orak\auto.bat`

Following script was used

```
@echo off

set "SERVICENAME=tomcat7installer"
set "LOGFILEPATH=E:\orak\file.txt"

echo ----------------------- >> %LOGFILEPATH%
echo %DATE% %TIME%  WAITING 3 SEC>> %LOGFILEPATH% 
rem ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

rem net stop %SERVICENAME% 
echo %DATE% %TIME% service stopped  >> %LOGFILEPATH%
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
net start %SERVICENAME%
echo %DATE% %TIME% service started  >> %LOGFILEPATH%
```

When outofmemory error occurs it stops the tomcat service. Tomcat logs show that the service could not be stopped where as tomcat in acutal is stopped but does not start again.

Why doesn't it start up again?

Comment: Presumably tomcat already stopped by the time the JVM catches the OOME and calls your script...

Comment: Is the service name really tomcat7*installer*?

Comment: yes...had several versions installed...testing on staging :)